# Python - Suppressing creation of __dict__ class variable in a subclass

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having a tricky problem in the game I'm working on. I'm using Pygame to develop it. I happen to be one of those developers who never uses the default`__dict__` object variable; I always define `__slots__` to clarify the variables an object can have (I have a classmethod that reads the slots to determine the variables needed from a config file).

Anyway, I just realized that this effort isn't working in some of my classes; they still have a `__dict__` variable and can have arbitrary attributes assigned to, even though they explicitly define their `__slots__`. I think this is because they are inheriting from pygame.sprite.Sprite, which has a `__dict__`. If this is the case, how do I suppress creation of this dict? (I though explicitly defining `__slots__` was supposed to) Or could I be mistaken about the cause? Thanks for any insight; it's hard to find information about this particular problem via searches.

Comment: If you explain the reason you are doing that, there may be a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to suppress arbitrary attributes and the `__dict__` container of them, is to use `__slots__` as you are *and inherit from a class that does the same*. A subclass of a class that has a `__dict__` will always have a `__dict__`. The only way around it is to not inherit from this class (but, for example, use [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) instead.)

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Thanks for the quick response.